# Unable to delete file using file.delete()?

Tags: android

I am writing a sync operation between 2 folders.

first, the target folder would delete all its .bmp files.
next, the .bmp files from the source folder will be copied to the target folder

I am currently on the first step, trying to delete all .bmp files on target folder.
when i use `file.delete()` , the file is deleted when viewed inside my phone's file explorer. 
but when i view via my pc, the file is still inside.

I've tried replugging my usb cable to my phone. the deleted files are still in there.

any idea whats wrong?

heres what i've done:

```
 private void getBMPfiles() {

    Log.d("getBMPFiles", "sourcePath is: " + targetPath);

    File targetDirector1 = new File(targetPath);
    File[] files = targetDirector1.listFiles();
    for (File file : files){
        String filename=file.getAbsolutePath();
        if(filename.endsWith(".bmp")){
            Log.i("deleting: ",filename);
            file.delete();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: you can delete all file from the folder..

Comment: `the file is deleted when viewed inside my phone's file explorer. but when i view via my pc, the file is still inside.`. Dont worry. Your phone's file explorer is right. The files are deleted. After a reboot of your phone you will not see them on your PC anymore too.

Comment: `file.delete();`. You are not checking the return value of delete(). If it cannot delete the file it would return false. With this code you know nothing.

Comment: @greenapps I've added a check to check if `file.delete()` is successful. changed code here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47120884/8642522)[link]

Comment: You should not have posted that minimal code change as an answer. Makes no sense as your real problem was that you thought that the files were not deleted as you still saw them on your pc. You have not reacted on comments telling you the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to greenapps and Fatih Ozcan,

I've changed my code to

```
private void getBMPfiles() {

Log.d("getBMPFiles", "sourcePath is: " + targetPath);

File targetDirector1 = new File(targetPath);
File[] files = targetDirector1.listFiles();
for (File file : files){
    String filename=file.getAbsolutePath();
    if(filename.endsWith(".bmp")){
        Log.i("deleting: ",filename);
        boolean delCheck = file.delete();
            if (delCheck==true){
                Log.d("getBMPFiles", "Deleted: " + dfilename);
            }
            else if(delCheck==false){
                Log.d("getBMPFiles", "error deleting: " + dfilename);
            }
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
void deletAllFile() {
    String[] myFiles;
    File extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "targertfolder");
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        myFiles = file.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < myFiles.length; i++) {
            File myFile = new File(file, myFiles[i]);
            myFile.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: my bad, i realise i didnt upload what i've done so far. edited my question with my code. 
i believe your answer and my code are the same?

Comment: Yes they are the same and equal bad as the return value of .delete() is not checked too.

Answer (score 0):

delete method returns Boolean, first check if it's returning true. lf it returns false, as far i've seen so far you can't delete a file from SD card using an absolute path if SD card is not set as internal memory, if anyone knows way to delete from SD card above KitKat feel free to correct me. To delete files, it's best to use an Uri with Documentfile or DocuementContract class delete methods